# how to make a java program with a loop of IO tasks faster?

Tags: java, io

I've written a program to find password of a zip file using zip4j. I've used bruteforce method, therefore each password should be checked on file using below code:

```
while(true)
try
{
  zipFile.setPassword(passstr);
  zipFile.extractAll(deststr);
  break;
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{ 
    //passstr = next password string to be checked
}
```

but this is so slow because of io-related task repeated in the loop each time!
is there any other way to check the password of zip file? or do i need to move the file to memory somehow and make it faster? or any any other solution to speed it up?

thanks

Comment: What type is `zipFile`? There is no `setPassword` method in `java.util.zip.ZipFile`.

Comment: hey neha, if you found any answer use ful then please accept it...

Comment: hi Javier, zipFile is an object of the class zip4j -which is written for handling zip files in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force is a [Embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem. You should try to use one thread per core for solving this problem.

In addition you should (as you said) avoid I/O. For this find a way to load the file to memory and test the password without using I/O. (You should try to minimize the test duration also, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Encryption) and this [spec](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) it appears that zip files may contain an encrypted header which will be faster to test the password in - if some test is possible).

Combining parallel and memory solutions, it is obvious that you should use one copy of the file in memory for each thread.

Finally try to use the fastest decryption implementation you can find. (do it in c mabybe?)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Shall test copying file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

try the following logic.

- start the program
- the path of the folder should be shared with the java program.
- first make copies of the zip file multiple depending on your need in
  the same folder.
- next start separate threads for each copy that you have created.
- execute the password crack process with each thread containing
  different set of brute force dictionary.
- keep a common flag in the class which will be false initially and
  each thread will follow that flag for execution
- lastly, when any thread returns true with a solution, it sets the
  flag and all other threads stop processing.

the number of threads can be set as per need or as per performance

Comment: I have two additions: a. don't use the harddrive for the copies, create in-memory copies. b. the number of threads should be the number of actual processors times some number. To avoid cutting your preformance by scheduling related processing.

Comment: i agree, but as the simplest suggestion this will be best. as taking the copy into memory will create memory issues in case the zip file is huge in size.

also the number of threads can be increased to 2 or 3 times the number of processors if the processing is short.

the java processor can handle that much load.

Comment: That's what I meant by times some number, thanks for clearing up my comment. To clear up my comment: I meant `numberOfProcessors * n = numberOfThreads` where `n` is any Integer (it shouldn't be too high though)

Comment: Thanks both for your help. I've used mapreduce in order to parallelize the program. The main issue is IO time, which is quite big compared to the rest of the process. I think copying the file (which is not too big) into memory would help.

Answer (score 0):

As Vineet has already mentioned, applying threading will improve performance somewhat.  However a more sophisticated approach would be to:

- Determine what encryption algorithm is being used by the file
- Read the file once into memory
- Fire off several threads to decrypt the raw data with your generated password
- depending on the library / decrypt mechanism you will either get an exception or a random jumble of bits as a result - in which case check the first few bytes for the file signature of a zip file.

Be prepared to wait for a few thousand years if the person who protected the file knows how to generate a secure password though!

Comment: winzip encryption algorithm is proprietary i think.

also in case the file has multiple encryption algorithms or there can be files with different logic.. also in case of digest algorithms, the decryption logic best known is bruteforce or dictionary attack..

Comment: I worked on finding encryption algorithms, but as Vineet said it is not that easy! However I'll check this option too if I cant find better way. thanks